# Regex: extract value from double quotes

Tags: regex

having a hard time to find regex solution.

The value in database's field "product_id" can be in either format:

```
{"value":"e19f2b3e-9919-421e-a125-95fdd989459d"}
{"itemUuid":"8fe2a09e-aade-485c-b847-e83a780f1b8e"}
```

Need to write a regex capturing BOTH cases, so the result will be:

```
e19f2b3e-9919-421e-a125-95fdd989459d
8fe2a09e-aade-485c-b847-e83a780f1b8e
```

What I already did (in Vertica syntax) is

```
 trim(TRAILING '"}' from  regexp_substr(me.value, '[0-9].*'))
```

which doesn't capture the id if it starts with alphabetic character.

Comment: I did this 

trim(TRAILING '"}' from  regexp_substr(me.value, '[0-9].*'))

(it is vertica database syntax)

Unfortunately, it doesn't capture the id if it starts with a letter.

So looking for other solutions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=:").+(?="})`](https://regex101.com/r/4BdqsH/1)

- `(?<=:")` makes sure there is `:"` before your match
- `.+` matches any char at least once
- `(?="})` makes sure there is`"}` after your match

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/4BdqsH/1)

Comment: Hi Zenoo, your solution worked for me. Thank you so much for clear explanation - it is the most important.